# Box plots in pandas - beginner's difficulty

Tags: pandas

I have a data frame num_data, with

```
num_data.columns

Index(['Q0', 'Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4', 'Q5', 'Q6', 'Q7', 'Q8', 'Q9', 'Q10',
   'Q11', 'Q12', 'Q13', 'Q14', 'Q15', 'Q16', 'Q17', 'Q18', 'Q19', 'Q20',
   'Q21', 'Q22', 'Q23', 'Q24', 'Q25', 'Q26', 'site', 'schools', 'school'],
  dtype='object')
```

when I try to make a box plot

```
num_data.boxplot(column = 'Q7')
```

I get a traceback with:

```
KeyError: "['Q7'] not in index"
```

I've searched the docs and the examples, and there is obviously something that this beginner does not understand. I eventually like to make some grouped box plots, but I'm stuck...

I would be grateful for a pointer !

Thanks very much.

Comment: Can you access the `column - Q7`  by `num_data['Q7']`?

Comment: Thanks Nickil. I can access the column with that expression

Comment: So are you able to get a `boxplot`? If not, could you share the `head` of the dataframe?

Comment: head() result -  I hope the formatting is OK

Q0                                                  Q1         Q2 Q3 Q4 Q5    Q6  Q7

1 2016-08-01 15:29:46.188 Year 3B a NaN NaN NaN NaN 3

2 2016-08-01 15:32:33.855 Year 3B b NaN NaN NaN NaN 4

3 2016-08-01 15:35:10.884 Year 4C NaN c NaN NaN NaN 4

4 2016-08-01 15:35:51.920 Year 4C NaN d NaN NaN NaN 3

5 2016-08-01 15:36:12.453 Year 4C NaN e NaN NaN NaN 2

Answer (score 0):

Boxplots can made only from `numerical` columns, not from `object` columns, so try one of these:

```
num_data['Q7'] = num_data['Q7'].astype(int)
num_data['Q7'] = num_data['Q7'].astype(float)
```